# Add a custom field below billing country in Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, select, woocommerce, checkout

I'm using `WordPress 5.0.2` with `WooCommerce 3.5.3` and I have a custom select dropdown field with optgroup on the checkout page, the field work as expected but it appear after the order note and I would like that it appear below the `billing_country` field.

[image]

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_select_field_with_optgroup', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_select_field_with_optgroup( $checkout ) {
    $domain  = 'woocommerce';
    $title   = __("Region", $domain);
    $slug    = sanitize_title($title);
    $default = __("Select your region", $domain);
    $value   = $checkout->get_value($slug);

    // Region option data array with optgroup
    $options = array(
        __("North Region", $domain) => array(
            'region1' => __("Region 1", $domain),
            'region2' => __("Region 2", $domain),
        ),
        __("South Region", $domain) => array(
            'region3' => __("Region 3", $domain),
            'region4' => __("Region 4", $domain),
        )
    );

    // The field
    echo '<p class="form-row form-row-wide '.$slug.'-dropdown" id="'.$slug.'_field" data-priority="">
    <label for="'.$slug.'" class="">'.$title.'</label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <select name="'.$slug.'" id="'.$slug.'" class="select " data-placeholder="" autocomplete="'.$slug.'">
    <option value="">'.$default.'</option>';

    // Loop through "optgroup"
    foreach( $options as $optgroup_label => $optgroup_options ) {
        echo '<optgroup label="'.$optgroup_label.'">';
        // Loop through "options" in the "optgroup"
        foreach( $optgroup_options as $key => $label ) {
            $selected = $value === $key ? ' selected="selected"': '';
            echo '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$selected.'>'.$label.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</optgroup>';
    }

    echo '</select></span></p>';
}
```

The code comes this previous thread: [WooCommerce Select Dropdown With Optgroup On Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942586/woocommerce-select-dropdown-with-optgroup-on-checkout/)

I'm aware that this custom field is not hooked to the `woocommerce_checkout_fields`, And if I do so, it doesn't show the field because I guess that this custom select field is not pulled from the `class-wc-countries.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Github thread adds to WooCommerce available form field types a **select field with options group** "`select_og`". Get it on **Github**: [lomars / Woocommerce select field with option group](https://github.com/lomars/woocommerce-select-form-field-with-options-group/blob/master/add-field-type-select-optgroup.php)

This code is required for this answer.

Now you will be able to include a custom select field with option groups in Woocommerce form fields like checkout billing and shipping fields.

Here is that code for your Billing and shipping region field:

```
// Custom function that returns the options data array for "Region" field
function wc_get_region_options_data( $domain ){
    return [
        '' => __("Choose an option…"),
        __("North Region", $domain) => [
            'region1'   => __("Region 1", $domain),
            'region2'   => __("Region 2", $domain),
        ],
        __("South Region", $domain) => [
            'region3'   => __("Region 3", $domain),
            'region4'   => __("Region 4", $domain),
            'region5'   => __("Region 5", $domain),
            'region6'   => __("Region 6", $domain),
        ],
        __("East Region", $domain)  => [
            'region7'   => __("Region 7", $domain),
            'region8'   => __("Region 8", $domain),
            'region9'   => __("Region 9", $domain),
        ],
    ];
}

// Custom function that returns the "Region" field data array
function wc_get_region_field( $fields, $group ){
    $domain   = 'woocommerce';
    $options  = wc_get_region_options_data( $domain );
    $priority = (int) $fields[$group.'_country']['priority'];

    $fields[$group.'_region'] = array(
        'label'    => __("Region", $domain),
        'type'     => 'select_og',
        'class'    => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'required' => true,
        'priority' => $priority + 5,
        'options'  => $options,
        'clear'    => true,
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Include region field in billing section after billing country
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'region_select_billing_field_with_optgroup', 10, 1 );
function region_select_billing_field_with_optgroup( $billing_fields ) {
    $billing_fields = wc_get_region_field( $billing_fields, 'billing' );
    return $billing_fields;
}

// Include region field in shipping section after shipping country
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'region_select_shipping_field_with_optgroup', 10, 1 );
function region_select_shipping_field_with_optgroup( $shipping_fields ) {
    $shipping_fields = wc_get_region_field( $shipping_fields, 'shipping' );
    return $shipping_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Related: [WooCommerce Select Dropdown With Optgroup On Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942586/woocommerce-select-dropdown-with-optgroup-on-checkout/53943589#53943589)